# Thread execution order Java

Tags: java, multithreading, initialization

*PhysicsThread.java* starts a new thread. The run method executes the initialize method. This method creates the physics world. After that, it starts a while loop that updates the world with an interval of 1000/60 = 16 milliseconds. However, I get a `nullpointerexception` in the loop, because it does not always know world, even though I check for that. **Can explain what is happening?**

**PhysicsThread.java**

```
public class PhysicsThread implements Runnable {

long fps = 60;
DiscreteDynamicsWorld dw;
long lasttime = System.currentTimeMillis();;

static int maxPhysicsObjects = 50000;

PhysicsThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Start thread");
    init();
    System.out.println("Start threadloop");

    while(true) {
        loop();
    }
}

public void init() {
    BroadphaseInterface broadphase = new AxisSweep3_32(new Vector3f(0,0,0), new Vector3f(200000,200000,200000), maxPhysicsObjects);//new DbvtBroadphase();
    DefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration = new DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    CollisionDispatcher dispatcher = new CollisionDispatcher(
            collisionConfiguration);

    SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver = new SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();

    dw = new DiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase,
            solver, collisionConfiguration);
    System.out.println("Made world");
    dw.setGravity(new Vector3f(0, 0, -10));
}

public void loop() {
    if (dw!=null) {
        float delta = System.currentTimeMillis()-lasttime;
        lasttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        dw.stepSimulation(delta/1000f, 1, 1/60f);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000/fps);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public DiscreteDynamicsWorld getWorld() {
    return dw;
}
```

}

Comment: Strange, `dw` get's initialized before the `loop` method is called. Which line produces the NPE? The first few lines of a stacktrace could be helpful.

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting NPE inside the if that checks if `dw` is not null? That should not be possible, unless some other thread is changing `dw` to null in the meantime, which I don't think is happening.

Comment: You are not showing your real code, unless `dw.stepSimulation()` produces an NPE internally, it can't be in your `loop` code above.

Comment: @stryba - `dw` could be null if it's modified *after* the initial null-check.  We are talking about threads here, and `System.currentTimeMillis` is the sort of thing that probably needs to go to an external bus and is likely to lead to context-switching (or just another thread executing a lot of CPU instructions in the meanwhile).

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle: I agree in case dw is set to `null` from another thread, but as I said that's not happening with the code the OP provide, hence my objection he is not showing his real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this may be down to your construction technique, which is an antipattern.  You shouldn't let the `this` reference "escape" during a constructor, because then other threads may see the object in a partially-constructed state.  At this point, all bets are off about the state of the class, and even invariants that are always true (such as final fields being set to a value) may not hold.

I wonder if what is happening here might be due to the following sequence of events:

- The constructor is called and starts the new thread based on `this`.
- The new thread runs, and fully executes `init` (setting `dw`), and half of `loop`, before being pre-empted.
- The main thread continues with the constructor, and sets `dw` to `null` as part of field initialisation.
- The spawned thread continues after working out `delta` and `lastTime`, then sees a null value for `dw`.

I'm a little hesistant to say that's *exactly* the case because I would have expected the fields to be initialised before the constructor body runs.  However it seems likely that accessing the fields while the object is still being constructed is a very bad idea.

In order to fix this I'd suggest *not* starting a thread in the constructor, but rather having the calling code start the thread afterwards, e.g.:

```
final PhysicsThread pt = new PhysicsThread();
final Thread t = new Thread(pt);
t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t.start();
```

(Also, the idea of having `init` methods that aren't the constructor is usually a bad idea - if the `dw` field never changes, why not perform all the work of `init` during the constructor itself and mark `dw` as `final`?  This will be cleaner and make your code easier to reason about, since the VM guarantees the value will be fully set during construction and that it will never change afterwards.  The only downside is a performance hit if you construct lots of these instances and never actually run them - so just don't do that. :)

Plus the class name is misleading, since this isn't a `Thread` but a `Runnable`.  Calling it something like `PhysicsTask` or `PhysicsSimulationRun` would arguably be clearer.)

Comment: `dw` will not be set to `null` at the end of the constructor. Would be weird to have a field reset to `null` after you set it up.

Comment: You'd also want to do `final Thread t=new Thread(pt)` I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried what you said, and it works, so that is great. I don't fully understand why I have to use the final keyword for this though. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @stryba Thanks for pointing out the typo in the example code, fixed.  And you're right that it would be weird to have a field reset - that's why you don't publish references to `this` during construction, because lots of invariants stop holding if you do!  (You may be right in this specific case, but if `dw` was explicitly set to null at the end of the constructor, it would be functionally identical and would *definitely* be prone to the problem described above.  Optimising compilers therefore may choose to rewrite the code like this because it shouldn't make any difference.)

Comment: @Gmfreaky Glad it helped!  The important part of this fix was not starting the thread in the constructor, that should have resolved the problem on its own.  Using `final` for things that don't change is merely good practice, as it makes your code *much* easier to reason about.

Comment: I don't think it's that the reference is set to null at the end of the constructor, but that the initialization isn't visible to the other thread until after the constructor finishes due to leaking this. This allows the initial null to overwrite the assignment done in the thread.